# compile google play service

Tags: android, gps, dependencies, google-play-services

I know this question is really simple for the persons experimented with android but please help me.
I followed this tutorial :
https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/android-location-api-using-google-play-services-example/
to the latitude and longitude of my device.

My problem is this part :

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0"
}
```

I tried to do the same with my own code :

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-service:8.3.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

but when I synchronize the project I get this error :

```
fail to resolve:com.google.android.gms:play-service:8.3.0
```

So in my SDK manager I downloaded the google play service but here's my problem :
How can I check the version of my 'com.google.android.gms:play-service'
???

EDIT :

The version I searched for was 10.2.1
If you have the same problem check File->Project Structure->Dependencies->'+' and check version. It works on AVD now but with it you have a new error :

My gradle.build (app)

[image: manifest]

with error :
[image]

EDIT 2 : if you have the same error check https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup
and select what you want (exemple compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.1')

Comment: refer this link : https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup.. you are using older version of google play service.

Comment: show your project gradle..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you connected to internet while sync gradle. its only for first time to download the gradle.

Make sure install/update latest Google Repository and Google Play Services in SDK Manager
[image]

**Avoid** using `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.1'` because it is **terribly heavy and cause Dex problem**. use individual dependencies instead. If you insist want to use it, enable `multiDexEnabled true`

[image]

If you are using Google Firebase, dont forget to add `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'` then add this `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` at the bottom of the `app/build.gradle`

P/s:
Please invalidate/cache and restart AS

Comment: I have google play services version 39 and google repository version 46 as well but when I synchronize (with internet) without 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.1' all my import com.google.android arn't reconized

Comment: Yeah I tried it but same result :/ and with "compile 'come.google.android....'" I have a new error (I will post it an edit)

Comment: add classpath `com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0` then add this apply plugin: `com.google.gms.google-services` at the bottom of the app/build.gradle.. this must be working

Comment: ah.. i see your problem.. like i said Avoid using compile `com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.1` because it is terribly heavy and cause Dex problem. Use individual dependencies instead. IF you still want to use it, please enable multidex `multiDexEnabled true` inside defaultConfig in app/gradle

Comment: What is individual dependencies ? I checked it but still don't understand what I must do to make it work fine ...

Comment: see this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43407318/how-to-suppress-the-avoid-using-bundled-version-of-google-play-services-sdk-wa/43407421#43407421

Comment: I tried multiDexEnabled true but it didn't solve anything. So if I find the dependencies I need for my app in 'com.google.android.gms' I should be able to synch without any problem, is that right ? By the way thanks for the fast answer and helping me solving my problem :)