# Compilation time in Android Studio is more than one hour

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

Faced with such a problem that the application compiles for a very long time. I tried to clean the cache - with no result
Changed the settings in `build.gradle` - no result
Moreover, I have a similar project in terms of code volume and it compiles on the same configuration files for no more than a couple of minutes.

[image: Profiling]

`Android Studio Fox 2020.3.1 Patch 3` -
`AGP 7.0.4` -
`Gradle 7.0.2` -
`Kotlin 1.6.21`

Comment: How much RAM are you allowing AS and gradle?  Have you tried increasing it?

Comment: Android Studio - 4g, Gradle - 2g

Comment: Way too low.  Increase it, especially gradle.  The more you can give it, the better.  What happens is it runs out of memory, then begins thrashing.  Compilation requires a lot of small objects (tokens and strings) to be allocated constantly.  So it will constantly be freeing stuff up, going OOM again, freeing stuff up, going OOM.  Performance goes to zero.

Comment: @GabeSechan I set the value to 8g, but apparently this did not help, the compilation has been going on for 27 minutes, still stuck on :app:compileGooglePlayDebugKotlin

Comment: Instead of installing all the Google Play services you might want to install only the deps you need. Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/43681342/13088785

Comment: @vpuonti the project does not have this dependency, only those that are needed, firebase, chastlytics, messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by deleting `kotlin-android-extensions` and rewrite all code where was it by used

Answer (score -1):

Try `invalidate cache and restart`. if it doesn't work delete `.gradle` folder under `user` folder. If it doesnt work too. You can try stable Android Studio version. Because you use canary version it may be real source of problem. You know it is very buggy usually.

Comment: did not help, tested with the current stable version (Android Studio Dolphin 2021.3.1)

Comment: try to activate gradle daemon.. Maybe your gradle configurations is wrong. and disable kotlin kapt too