# duplicated class caused by mulitedex dependecy in Android Studio

Tags: android, class, signed, android-multidex

thank you for your support.
My issue is : When I added the `multidex` dependecy and try to export the signed apk, I get this error :

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':androidKeyboardThemes:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'.
>
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/location/ActivityRecognition$1.class

My gradle dependecies are theses:

```
 dependencies {
    compile project(':cropper')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile files('libs/StartAppInApp-2.4.7.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

I tried to delete one lib or jar at any time and build again but I couldn't get the job done.
Also I read all the unswer about duplicated class in stackoverflow but I failed again to solve my issue.
Any ideas?, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
dependencies {
compile project(':cropper')
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'   <-- choose either one
compile files('libs/StartAppInApp-2.4.7.jar')
compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')     <-- choose either one
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1' 
}
```

Whatever it is, please dont use play-services. inside compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+' contains alot of dependencies.. see below.. using play-services may cause dex problem and heavy app. refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43407318/how-to-suppress-the-avoid-using-bundled-version-of-google-play-services-sdk-wa/43407421#43407421)

Comment: thank you for your unswer;
It works with this:
**gradle:**

`dependencies {
    compile project(':cropper')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:10.2.1'
    // All of them except pay, map and location
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:10.2.1'
    compile files('libs/StartAppInApp-2.4.7.jar')
    //compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1
}`

But still when I tested the APK to install it on my device it took 85 s. Any the major problem is solved, thank you @Saurabh and @ZeroOne.