# My app violates the Android Advertising ID policy

Tags: android, google-play, imei

Google Play Team has rejected my app because:

> The advertising identifier must not be connected to
>   personally-identifiable information or associated with any persistent
>   device identifier (for example: SSAID, MAC address, IMEI, etc.)
>   without explicit consent of the user.
>
> For example, we have identified that your app's attribution SDK
>   enables collection of IMEI from devices which have an Android
>   advertising ID without prominent disclosure, which is a violation of
>   our Android Advertising ID policy.

I'm not collecting the `IMEI` explicitly so the `IMEI` must be accessed by one of the dependencies of the app.

How I could detect which one is accessing to the `IMEI`?

**Updated:**
These are my dependencies

```
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$support_version"
    compile "com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:$support_version"      // I'm using icons from here, like ic_media_pause and such
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$support_version"
    compile "com.android.support:design:$support_version"
    compile "com.android.support:support-compat:$support_version"

    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'

    // individual dependencies -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/43407421/1121497
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:$gms_version"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:$gms_version"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:$gms_version"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:$gms_version"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:$gms_version"

    compile "com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:$facebook_version"
    compile 'com.facebook.android:notifications:1.0.2'

    compile 'com.batch.android:batch-sdk:1.11.0'

    compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.9'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.3'
    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.photoview:library:1.2.2'
    compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
    compile 'info.hoang8f:android-segmented:1.0.5'
    compile 'io.card:android-sdk:5.4.2'
    compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9'
    compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r2.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.2.0'

    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.1.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.0'
    //compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava-joins:0.22.0' // to use JoinObservable (and-then-when combinator)

    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"

    // In libs we have:
    // - ZooZ 1.02 : From https://github.com/Zooz/Zooz-Android/releases/tag/1.02
    // - AppsFlyer : AF-Android-SDK 2.3.1.13 jar
    // - Volley
    compile fileTree(dir: '../libs', include: '*.jar')

    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.7.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
```

**Note**: `AppsFlyer` has been configured as:

```
        AppsFlyerLib.setCollectIMEI(false); // https://play.google.com/about/monetization-ads/ads/ad-id/
        AppsFlyerLib.setCollectMACAddress(false);
        AppsFlyerLib.setCollectAndroidID(false);
```

Comment: Can you please post your gradle dependencies

Comment: Do you have `android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE` permission in your `manifest`? Do you need it ? You cannot get `IMEI` without it (for API >4).See also [Attribution & Analytics SDKs](http://blog.safedk.com/sdk-economy/attribution-mobile-app-sdks-need-to-know/)For reference [Best practices for unique identifiers](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids). Could be `crashlytics` ?

Comment: Yes, I have the `android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE` permission. I'm not sure what I will break removing this permission. I'm going to check the resources you provided, thanks. Why do you suspect `crashlytics`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using Appsflyer below sdk 4.3. This is the problem.
This is the email they sent all developers.

> Hi there,
>
> The AppsFlyer and Google Play teams are collaborating to ensure that
>   all advertisers using the AppsFlyer SDK are compliant with the Google
>   Play privacy policy. To avoid any disruption to your business, we
>   strongly encourage that all advertisers take the following steps.
>
> If you are running the AppsFlyer SDK version 4.3 or earlier: Please
>   update to the latest AppsFlyer SDK as soon as possible to maintain
>   full compliance. If you have enabled IMEI collection in a newer SDK
>   version: Disable IMEI collection via the AppsFlyer SDK by removing the
>   following code
>   AppsFlyerLib.getInstance().setImeiData("IMEI_DATA_HERE") If your apps
>   are not yet compliant with the Google Play privacy policy, we
>   recommend that you correct your data collection in a timely manner.
>   For more information about the AppsFlyer SDK, please visit the Help
>   Center or contact your success manager.
>
> Thank you, The AppsFlyer Team

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Bruno I appreciate it. However I would like to know if exists a procedure/application/whatever to detect who is accessing to IMEI instead of checking each dependency individually (depending of the project could be really hard work). Fortunately my app has been approved so I'm just curious in case it happens to me again.

Comment: @ilopezluna Hi. I have the same problem in my app. Was it the appsflyer that caused the rejection? How do you initialize the appsflyer in the latest version to make sure it doesn't collection the IMEI then? Thanks!

Comment: We have added the following lines: 

 `AppsFlyerLib.setCollectIMEI(false); // https://play.google.com/about/monetization-ads/ads/ad-id/
          AppsFlyerLib.setCollectMACAddress(false);
          AppsFlyerLib.setCollectAndroidID(false);`

**Note**: we are not using the latest version.

Answer (score 20):

My application is also removed by Google. I have done the following method to republish it.

1. Create a privacy policy of application using [Free Privacy Policy URL](https://www.freeprivacypolicy.com/free-privacy-policy-generator.php)
2. Publish the privacy policy at [URL](https://sites.google.com/new)
3. Copy the published privacy policy link and add it in Developer Play Console.
4. Add the privacy policy link in Application also (Optional)

Hope this will help you also.

Comment: Perfect ! Note that now on the first website is hosting your privacy policy so you don't even have to use the second link.

Answer (score 14):

***Crashlytics*** uses a variety of identifiers to provide their services including the Android ID, and the ***Android Advertising ID***.

So **crashlytics lib** can be an issue. This lib is dealing with advertising ID. Many of developer getting this warning who are using crashlytics lib and not using AppsFlyerLib. 
So I think you should also be concern about crashlytics library.

For more clarification you can visit [crashlytics security page](http://try.crashlytics.com/security/)

Comment: Can you send an evidence? For example a link.

Comment: If you go through this link you will get clarification about the info http://try.crashlytics.com/security/

Answer (score 5):

> You have to add privacy policy on your application.

First, you have to create a privacy policy URL and then add this URL in *GOOGLE PUBLISHER CONSOLE* based on application. You can easily create privacy policy using this website.

[Privacy Policies](https://privacypolicies.com/)

If you have a server/host try to upload privacy policy page on your own server otherwise you can use this website for storing.

**Mentioned**: you have to add this policy page on your application. Create a menu as privacy police and show all your policy content on a dialog. Easiest way

Comment: Only adding the privacy policy to the google play store listing does not work.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was due privacy policy URL was not set in Google Play Console. I also use Crashlytic. But when I added Privacy Policy, it took some time to process and then it got resolved.
I didnt event had to re-publish it again.

Comment: How is your answer different from other answers that proceeded yours?