# Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-1

Tags: java, android-studio

Im trying to connect my Android app to Google Calander API and i got stucked.
i have many errors about duplicate in my app and dont know why.
I updated all my modules up to date.
**my errors:**

```
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-12.0.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:12.0.1) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement$ConditionalUserProperty found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-12.0.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:12.0.1) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement$Event found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-12.0.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:12.0.1) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement$EventInterceptor found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-12.0.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:12.0.1) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement$OnEventListener found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-12.0.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:12.0.1) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement$Param found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-12.0.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:12.0.1) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement$UserProperty found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-12.0.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:12.0.1) and play-services-measurement-impl-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.2.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-12.0.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:12.0.1) and play-services-measurement-api-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:17.2.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics$Event found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-12.0.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:12.0.1) and play-services-measurement-api-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:17.2.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics$Param found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-12.0.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:12.0.1) and play-services-measurement-api-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:17.2.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics$UserProperty found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-12.0.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:12.0.1) and play-services-measurement-api-17.2.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:17.2.1)
```

**my gradle**:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.1'
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0"
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-calendar:v3-rev401-1.25.0'
    implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.30.7'
    implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.30.7'
    implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-gson:1.19.1'
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'  dependency and use individual dependency instead.Inside com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1 contains a lot of dependencies. using play-services may cause dex problem and heavy app. Select only which do your really depends to.
[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43407421/9702409)